# I can't curl the finger like the one shown in the YT video Im following, any idea?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, armature, bones

https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EeZRyOx9tRpBgBY1WFpS_7sBRYXN8Y5YdXsSif5F1o7R9A?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=XT2c6w

Need help with the insight on rigging bone to curl like what is shown in the youtube video[image]

Comment: Hello, in your armature your fingers seem to have only one phalange while in the video there are 3 per fingers, so I'm not sure what is your question?

Comment: @moonboots might be dumb question but is there a way to add phalange? does extruding it works?

Comment: select the bone in Edit mode and right click > Subdivide, then in the Operator box increase the subdivision

Comment: @moonboots thanks for the help~ I think I have one last ques, the newly created bone doesn't seem to attach to the finger while u manipulate it, is this related to parenting issue? any solution? Video Reference:
https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EbSI6tBNRrtLrj8ixYGeJ9wBvBVDKbQHWZuPLkyPFl8sQA?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=nt1JGI

Comment: As you had only one bone, only this one continues to act on the mesh, now you need to assign weights for the new bones. To do that, select the armature, shift select the mesh, switch to Weight Paint mode, Shift left click to select the desired bones, then in the top bar menu > Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones

Answer (score 1):

In your armature your fingers have only one phalange while in the video there are 3 per fingers, you need to subdivide your fingers in *Edit* mode: Select and <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Subdivide*, then in the *Operator Box* increase the *Number of Cuts* up to 2.

As you had only one bone, only this one continues to act on the mesh, now you need to assign weights for the new bones. To do that, select the armature, shift select the mesh, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> to select the desired bones, then in the top bar menu > *Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones*:

[image]

Edit: Before the operation, make sure that the armature is in its rest pose, select all the bones in *Pose* mode and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: been trying for awhile now, but I cant seemed to select anything use Shift +Left mouse in weight paint mode, any reason why?

Edit: also wanna thanks for the effort and time for helping and newbie shlt likes me, really appreciating it

Comment: If the mesh is still parented to the armature it should work, if it doesn't I don't understand why......    ://

Comment: I also tried Alt+Shift+right click, Im able to select added bone with it (weight paint mode) and assigned automatic from bones but  it still doesn't attach to the bone...

Comment: Please share your file as it is: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=aanzdJw4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/aanzdJw4/)

Edit: The layers in scene collection tab is messy, dnt trust it xD